Google Play Console предупреждение "В этой области экрана есть несколько элементов, которые реагируют на клики" для карты в SupportMapFragment
Столкнулся с предупреждением от Google Play Console при загрузке приложения:
"В этой области экрана есть несколько элементов, которые реагируют на клики. Путь к элементу - id/map".
У меня есть активити, где используется SupportMapFragment для отображения карты Google. Я удалил все дополнительные объекты и оставил только стандартный код для SupportMapFragment, который предоставляет Google. В XML разметке также нет других видимых или кликабельных элементов, которые могли бы накладываться на карту.
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private ActivityMapsBinding binding;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        binding = ActivityMapsBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());

        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
    }
}

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clickable="false"
    tools:context=".MapsActivity" />


Добавил android:clickable="false" для SupportMapFragment в XML.

Несмотря на это, Google Play Console продолжает выдавать предупреждение.
есть ли способ избавиться от предупреждения?
